# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null Springboot + Reactjs + MySQL

Tags: mysql, reactjs, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am having some trouble mapping (displaying) existing tuples in my local mysql database on my front end (Reactjs). I am receiving the following error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null".

I was able to display these records in the past, so I know I am close, but have spent all day trying to get just the existing records to show up in the view, and so am hoping for some guidance. I am not very familiar with reactjs, so I have a feeling the problem may reside somewhere on that end. I am able to successfully query the database via terminal and see respective reviews. Any information would be greatly appreciated!

ReviewList.js (react view):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, ButtonGroup, Container, Table } from 'reactstrap';
import AppNavbar from './AppNavbar';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class ReviewList extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {reviews: [], isLoading: true};

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({isLoading: true});

    fetch('api/reviews')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({reviews: data, isLoading: false}));
  }

  render() {
    const {reviews, isLoading} = this.state;

    if (isLoading) {
      return <p>Loading...</p>;
    }

    const reviewList = reviews.map(review => {
      const rev = `${review.name} ${review.itemName || ''} ${review.reviewDesc|| ''}`;
      return <tr key={review.id}>
        <td style={{whiteSpace: 'nowrap'}}>{review.id}</td>
        <td>{rev}</td>
      </tr>
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <AppNavbar/>
        <Container fluid>
          <div className="float-right">
            <Button color="success" tag={Link} to="/reviews/new">Add Review</Button>
          </div>
          <h3>Tell us how we are doing!</h3>
          <Table className="mt-4">
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th width="20%">Item Name</th>
              <th width="20%">Cost</th>
              <th>Review</th>
              <th width="10%">Actions</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {reviewList}
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ReviewList;
```

Review.java (model)

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.Set;

@Data
@Entity
//for jpa
@Table(name = "review")
public class Review {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    private String itemName;
    private String reviewDesc;
    private Date created;
  

}
```

ReviewController Snippet:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import com.seniorproject.redcarpet.model.Review;
import com.seniorproject.redcarpet.model.ReviewRepository;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
class ReviewController {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReviewController.class);
    @Autowired
    private ReviewRepository reviewRepository;

    public ReviewController(ReviewRepository reviewRepository) {
        this.reviewRepository = reviewRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/reviews")
    Collection<Review> reviews() {
        return reviewRepository.findAll();
    }
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/restapi?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=myuser..
spring.datasource.password=mypass..
```

Consoleoutput of console.log(reviews) in render()

[image: Consoleoutput of console.log(reviews) in render()]

Comment: What happens when you `console.log(reviews)`?

Comment: hi @wentjun, thanks for the response. After the initialization of reviews, I did the console log as you mentioned. I then saw in console, that there was a list of 6 tuples **(previously entered into the DB before I integrated it into the project)****. I then took the action of deleting these existing tuples and added a new one. When I refreshed the server, I am able to see the new entry! Now the question is...why would the tuples that existed prior to integration show up as null? THANKS FOR THE GUIDANCE!

Comment: Do you mind copying the output of console.log into here? Either the comments, or the question?

Comment: Well, now the previous entries prior to integration have been deleted. Is it still worth for me to post the output? It is just strange that the new entires work as expected when added.

Comment: render() {
    
    const {reviews, isLoading} = this.state;
    console.log(reviews);
    if (isLoading) {
      return <p>Loading...</p>;
    }

@wentjun adding screenshot to original question now...(new tuples show up)

Comment: No, I am referring to the printout response when you run `console.log(reviews)`

Comment: sure @wentjun, I just wanted to show you where i was doing the console.log, inside the render method. Picture is added now. Thank you. Since it works now, please make an answer and I will accept. If you have any insight as to why the older values were showing as null, that would be a bonus. Thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For folks that run into this scenario: I had to delete the existing tuples in the existing database and THEN when adding records, I was able to see them populate on my view in React. Thank you @wentjun for your tip on debugging. Doing a simple console.log(reviews) allowed me to see the number of existing tuples in the database, which helped me realize that somehow those tuples were showing up as null entries.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing this error because `const reviewList` is trying to initialize in the `render()` method, but `review` is `null`. The cause of the `null` is not clear, so you will need to step through your backend and frontend code to ensure that the data is being passed through each layer as expected.

You may need to restructure the logic in your React component. Make sure it only accesses the elements of reviews *after* the fetch and setState are complete. Put the logic that initializes the `reviewList` inside the final `then()` of your fetch. (You will need to declare `var reviewList` instead of `const reviewList` because the value is dynamic.)

Comment: Hi @bakeryenabler, I will take this into consideration. After the comment above however, I noticed something after doing a console.log(reviews): "After the initialization of reviews, I did the console log as you mentioned. I then saw in console, that there was a list of 6 tuples **(previously entered into the DB before I integrated it into the project)****. I then took the action of deleting these existing tuples and added a new one. When I refreshed the server, I am able to see the new entry! Now the question is...why would the tuples that existed prior to integration show up as null?"

Comment: review is not null. it is an empty array, as stated. on the constructor.

Comment: @wentjun reviewS is an array, but review is null